# Scrapy: error downloading with proxies

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I am able to scrape pages without using a proxy. However, when I add proxies, scrapy either gives `Error downloading: Connection was refused by other side: 61: Connection refused`, or `[<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion.>]`, or raises Timeout exception. Proxies are all in type http.

Here is what I add to `setting.py`

```
PROXIES = [{'ip_port': '213.136.90.232:8080', 'user_pass': ''},]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware' : 100,
    'judgeinfo.middleware.RotateUserAgentMiddleware' :1,
    'judgeinfo.middleware.ProxyMiddleware' :100,

}
```

And here is my middleware.py

```
import random
import base64 
from settings import PROXIES

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
def process_request(self, request, spider):
    proxy = random.choice(PROXIES)
    if proxy['user_pass'] is not None:
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy['user_pass'])
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
        print "**************ProxyMiddleware have pass************" + proxy['ip_port']
    else:
        print "**************ProxyMiddleware no pass************" + proxy['ip_port']
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
```

I have tested the proxies using curl and got back the correct responses.

```
curl -L 'http://IP:port' -v "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

I have also added randomly chosen USER_AGENT, and set DOWNLOAD_DELAY =  3

Comment: scrapy normally uses `b64encode` insteaf of `encodestring`, as `encodestring` adds a newline at the end of the encoded string, try stripping that string or using `b64encode("mystring").strip()`

Comment: That solves my problem! Thanks! @eLRuLL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completeness... (I hate having to find answers in comments)

middleware.py should be changed to:

```
import random
import base64 
from settings import PROXIES

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        proxy = random.choice(PROXIES)
        if proxy['user_pass'] is not None:
            request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
            encoded_user_pass = base64.b64encode(proxy['user_pass']).strip()
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
        print "**************ProxyMiddleware have pass************" + proxy['ip_port']
    else:
        print "**************ProxyMiddleware no pass************" + proxy['ip_port']
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://%s" % proxy['ip_port']
```

Comment: Thanks! I will check it out!